# matplotlib permissions denied on cygwin

Tags: matplotlib, permissions, cygwin

I tried to run this line `import pylab as pl`

```
File "lab.py", line 9, in <module>
   import pylab as pl
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib-1.4.3-py2.7-cygwin-1.7.35-x86_64.egg/pylab.py", line 1, in <module>
from matplotlib.pylab import *
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib-1.4.3-py2.7-cygwin-1.7.35-x86_64.egg/matplotlib/pylab.py", line 231, in <module>
   import matplotlib.finance
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib-1.4.3-py2.7-cygwin-1.7.35-x86_64.egg/matplotlib/finance.py", line 36, in <module>
from matplotlib.dates import date2num
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib-1.4.3-py2.7-cygwin-1.7.35-x86_64.egg/matplotlib/dates.py", line 137, in <module>
import matplotlib.ticker as ticker
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib-1.4.3-py2.7-cygwin-1.7.35-x86_64.egg/matplotlib/ticker.py", line 158, in <module>
from matplotlib import transforms as mtransforms
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib-1.4.3-py2.7-cygwin-1.7.35-x86_64.egg/matplotlib/transforms.py", line 39, in <module>
from matplotlib._path import (affine_transform, count_bboxes_overlapping_bbox,
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib-1.4.3-py2.7-cygwin-1.7.35-x86_64.egg/matplotlib/_path.py", line 7, in <module>
__bootstrap__()
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib-1.4.3-py2.7-cygwin-1.7.35-x86_64.egg/matplotlib/_path.py", line 6, in __bootstrap__
imp.load_dynamic(__name__,__file__)

ImportError: Permission denied
```

Is it due to some config which has to be done after installation of matplotlib?

Comment: What are the permissions on your site-packages directory?

Comment: How do I check that? How do I set the permissions? Which config file may I set it?

Comment: Go to the python2.7 directory ("cd /usr/lib/python2.7") and type "ls -l". This will display a list of all of the directories and files in python2.7 prefaced by a series of dashes and letters. The dashes and letters indicate the permissions.

Comment: If the site-packages directory has a - in the second position rather than an r, that means that you don't have read access, and would explain why you're getting this error.

Comment: it seems ok:
`drwx---rwx+ 1 0 Apr 18 18:09 matplotlib-1.4.3-py2.7-cygwin-1.7.35-x86_64.egg`

Comment: Hmmm. So the middle three positions represent group level permissions, whereas the first three represent user permissions. Python might be using group level permissions, and yours are all off. Try typing "chmod 777 matplotlib-1.4.3-py2.7-cygwin-1.7.35-x86_64.egg" and see if that fixes the problem.

Comment: @seaotternerd, pardon. I thought it work. It did not.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/75612/discussion-between-seaotternerd-and-ursa-major).